# How can I support SSIS package execution on both SQL Server 2008R2 & SQL Server 2012?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I need to support an execution of a specific SSIS package (created in VS 2012 SSIS designer) on both SQL Server 2008R2 & SQL Server 2012. I'm going to execute this package from C#, with the help of Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS dll (I can execute it also with DTEXEC.exe).
We have separated servers for Application & DB. The package sits in Application Server and communicates SQL Server through local Integration Services Service.

How can I support SSIS package execution on both SQL Server 2008R2 & SQL Server 2012?

Thanks

Comment: The obvious way to make this work would be to author it in the VS 2008 SSIS designer instead. Why is that not an option?

Comment: Thanks. I realized it right yesterday, and I'm going with this solution.